# How to save query statistics time in database?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, elapsedtime, cpu-time

I am able to get CPU time and elapsed time by using **Statistics Time On** in stored procedure in SQL, but the output is coming in messages window. How to fetch CPU time and elapsed time in the query so that i can save it in database?

OK Fine. I have got an answer and that is the use of :
**sys.dm_exec_query_stats**

but how to use above mention query ? It is not returning the CPU and elapsed time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing SQL STATISTICS TIME and IO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980084/capturing-sql-statistics-time-and-io)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Correct tagging gives the correct attention, i.e. better answers, faster.)

Comment: i am using sql server. and tagged sql as well.